# ¿Cómo escoger determinados elementos de una lista?

Tags: r, lista

Una pregunta, si yo tengo un objeto lista que me arroja resultados como estos:

```
$`WOE Table for frec_calificacion_4_1m12`
  Final.Bin Total.Count Total.Distr. 1.Count 0.Count 1.Distr. 0.Distr. 0.Rate  WOE    IV
1      <= 0        2195        98.6%     578    1617    98.5%    98.7%  73.7% -0.2 0.000
2    <= Inf          31         1.4%       9      22     1.5%     1.3%  71.0% 13.3 0.000
4     Total        2226       100.0%     587    1639   100.0%   100.0%  73.6%   NA 0.000

$`WOE Table for tea`
  Final.Bin Total.Count Total.Distr. 1.Count 0.Count 1.Distr. 0.Distr. 0.Rate WOE    IV
1     <= 49        2226       100.0%     587    1639   100.0%   100.0%  73.6% 0.0 0.000
2    <= Inf           0         0.0%       0       0     0.0%     0.0%   NaN% 0.0 0.000
4     Total        2226       100.0%     587    1639   100.0%   100.0%  73.6%  NA 0.000
```

cómo puedo hacer para ver todos mis elementos pero con solo algunas columnas? así:

```
$`WOE Table for frec_calificacion_4_1m12`
  Final.Bin  1.Distr. 0.Distr. 0.Rate  WOE    IV
1      <= 0   98.5%    98.7%   73.7%  -0.2  0.000
2    <= Inf    1.5%     1.3%   71.0%  13.3  0.000
4     Total  100.0%   100.0%   73.6%    NA  0.000

$`WOE Table for tea`
  Final.Bin  1.Distr. 0.Distr. 0.Rate  WOE    IV
1     <= 49    100.0%   100.0%  73.6%  0.0  0.000
2    <= Inf      0.0%     0.0%   NaN%  0.0  0.000
4     Total    100.0%   100.0%  73.6%   NA  0.000
```

he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera, pero no lo he logrado:

```
tablas <- qq[c(1:length(qq))][,c(1,6,7,8,9,10)]
tablas
```

donde qq es el objeto lista.

De antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes, mediante `lapply()` iterar sobre cada elemento y extraer las columnas deseadas:

```
lapply(qq, function(x) x[, c(1,6,7,8,9,10)])
```

Estoy asumiendo que `qq` es tu lista y cada elemento de las mismas es una matriz o `data.frame`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio!